# Issues Adding Agents to RSA Authentication Manager using the RSA Authentication Manager SDK

Tags: python, powershell, api, sdk

I am working on adding agents to our RSA Authentication Manager (8.X) via PowerShell using the RSA Authentication Manager SDK. I am able to query existing agents without issue using the following code:

```
$searchAgent = New-Object rsaapi.SearchAgentsCommand
$searchAgent = ($CommandServer.executeCommand($loginCommand.sessionId,$searchAgent)).agents
```

However, when trying to add a new agent, I get `"Cannot convert argument "in1", with value: "rsaapi.AgentDTO", for "executeCommand" to type "rsaapi.TargetableCommand": "Cannot convert the "rsaapi.AgentDTO" value of type "rsaapi.AgentDTO" to type "rsaapi.TargetableCommand".""` returned from the last line. Here is my code snippet:

```
$hostDTO = New-Object rsaapi.HostDTO
$hostDTO.name = $servername
$hostDTO.primaryIpAddress = $ipAddress

$agentDTO = New-Object rsaapi.AgentDTO
$agentDTO.name = $servername
$agentDTO.primaryAddress = $ipAddress
$agentDTO.agentType = 1
$agentDTO.offlineAuthDataRefreshRequired = $false
$agentDTO.restriction = $false
$agentDTO.securityDomainId = 'ims.securityDomainGUID'
$agentDTO.securityDomainName = 'securityDomainName'

$addAgent = New-Object rsaapi.AddAgentCommand
$addAgent = $CommandServer.executeCommand($loginCommand.sessionId,$agentDTO)
```

The AdminAPIDemo shows the Python code block below as how to add a new agent:

```
def createAgent(self, name, addr, alt, sdGuid):
    # need a HostDTO to be set
    host = HostDTO()
    host.setName(name)
    host.setPrimaryIpAddress(addr)
    host.setSecurityDomainGuid(sdGuid)
    host.setNotes("Created by AM Demo code")

    # the agent to be created
    agent = AgentDTO()
    agent.setName(name)
    agent.setHost(host)
    agent.setPrimaryAddress(addr)
    agent.setAlternateAddresses(alt)
    agent.setSecurityDomainId(sdGuid)
    agent.setAgentType(AgentConstants.STANDARD_AGENT)
    agent.setRestriction(1) # only allow activated groups
    agent.setEnabled(1)
    agent.setOfflineAuthDataRefreshRequired(0)
    agent.setNotes("Created by AM Demo code")

    cmd = AddAgentCommand(agent)

try:        
    cmd.execute()
    except DuplicateDataException:
        print "ERROR: Agent " + name + " already exists."
    sys.exit(2)
    
    # return the created agents GUID for further linking
    return cmd.getAgentGuid()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Working code to add agents via PowerShell to the RSA Authentication Manager console:

```
$hostDTO = New-Object rsaapi.HostDTO
$hostDTO.name = $servername
$hostDTO.primaryIpAddress = $ipAddress

$agentDTO = New-Object rsaapi.AgentDTO
$agentDTO.name = $servername
$agentDTO.host = $hostDTO
$agentDTO.primaryAddress = $ipAddress
$agentDTO.agentType = 1
$agentDTO.offlineAuthDataRefreshRequired = $false
$agentDTO.restriction = $true
$agentDTO.securityDomainId = 'ims.securityDomainGUID'
$agentDTO.securityDomainName = 'securityDomainName'

$addAgent = New-Object rsaapi.AddAgentCommand
$addAgent.agentDTO = $agentDTO
$addAgent = $CommandServer.executeCommand($loginCommand.sessionId,$addAgent)
```